# How to hold the selected button values when we go for paging in grid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I have two buttons in gridview ,`Link` and `UnLink`. When i click on `Link` it should show `UnLink` button, and also vice versa. Then we navigate to the next page of grid and return back to the parent page,the `UnLink` button doesn't stay. It changes to 'Link' button. How I hold the `Unlink` button on the paging of grid.
And My code is,

```
 $(document).off("click", ".Link").on("click", ".Link", function (e) {
        hiddenTicketId = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).hide();
        $('.UnLink').hide();
        $('.Link').show();
        var grid = $(".GridClass").data("kendoGrid"); //
        var gridData = grid.dataSource.data();
        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
            var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
            var currentRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
            if (hiddenTicketId == gridData[i].Id) {
                currentRow.find(".Link").hide();
                currentRow.find(".UnLink").show();

            }
        }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Ahaliya, Is this a ASP.NET server control?

Comment: no..it is mvc coding